# Java BitSet example - Can Palindrome algorithm

Tags: palindrome, bitset

How can I use bit manipulation in Java to check if an input string is a permutation of a palindrome? (rather than boolean array)

Answer (score 2):

Java BitSet can help with bit manipulations. there are many built-in methods to use with BitSet, some mentioned in comments below:

```
private static boolean canPalindrome(String wordStr) {

    BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(256);
    for (int i = 0; i < wordStr.length(); i++) {
        char letter = wordStr.charAt(i); // following letter ascii value
        if (letter != ' ') {    // space char ' ' does not affect the palindrome
            bitSet.flip(letter)   //flip turns 0->1 and 1->0;
        }
    }

    int cardinality = bitSet.cardinality(); //represents all '1' bits in BitSet
    return cardinality <= 1;   //Palindrome can hold 0-1 chars with ODD count
}
```

Basic idea here is to track number of times each letter appears. returning TRUE only if we have a max of 1 letter that appears an ODD number of times in wordStr.